# Clarification on Y values

Tags: probability

Suppose that X is a random variable where:

$$P(X = −1) = \frac{1}{4}$$ $$P(X = 0) = \frac{1}{2}$$ $$P(X = 1) =\frac{1}{4} $$
and let $Y = X^2 + 1$

What are the values of the following quantities:

**(Answer)**

$$P(Y = 2) = \frac{1}{4} +\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{2} $$
$$P(X = 0, Y = 2) = 0$$

What is the value of P(X ≥ Y /3)?

**Answer: P(X ≥ Y /3) = P(X = 1, Y = 2) = 1/4**

**How were these answers calculated?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y=2) = & ~\mathsf P(X^2+1 = 2) \\ = & ~\mathsf P(X= 1\cup X=-1) \\ = & ~\tfrac 1 4+\tfrac 1 4 \\ = & ~ \tfrac 1 2\end{align}$$

---

$X=0, Y=2$ can't happen because $Y$ is determined by $X$, via: $Y=X^2+1$.

$$\mathsf P(X=0, Y=2) = 0$$

---

Observe that $X\geq Y/3$ can only happen when $X=1$ (and $Y=1^2+1$).

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\geq Y/3) = & ~\mathsf P(X=1, Y=2) \\ = & ~\tfrac 1 4\end{align}$$

---

That is awl.

Answer (score 1):

Since the probabilities for $X$ add up to one, we have its complete pmf, and so there are exactly three cases to consider:

- If $X = -1$, then we know with certainty that $Y = (-1)^2 + 1 = 2$.
- If $X = 0$, then we know with certainty that $Y = 0^2 + 1 = 1$.
- If $X = 1$, then we know with certainty that $Y = 1^2 + 1 = 2$.

Thus, the full joint pmf is given by:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& Y = 1 & Y = 2 & \sum_y \\ \hline
X = -1 & 0 & 1/4 & 1/4 \\ \hline
X = 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\ \hline
X = 1 & 0 & 1/4 & 1/4 \\ \hline
\sum_x & 1/2 & 1/2 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the distribution (table) of $Y$. First notice the possible values of $Y$ are $\{1,2\}$. Then the table is
\begin{array}{c|c}
y&P(Y=y)\\\hline
1&1/2\\\hline
2&1/2\\
\end{array}
since $Y =1$ when $X=0$, and $Y=2$ otherwise.

For $P(X = 0, Y=2)$, is it possible for $X=0$ and $Y = 2$?

For $P(X\geq Y/3)$
$$P(X\geq Y/3) = \sum_{k=1}^2P(X\geq k/3, Y = k).$$